# I am trying to allow users to upload pictures via the TinyMCE editor and insert in the users post

Tags: django, tinymce

I am trying to allow users to upload images into their TinyMCE text area as they are writing their post. I currently have the TinyMCE text widget on the website, but when you click images, you have to type in a URL. I want them to be able to pick from their computer files.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for TinyMCE has an entire section on this topic:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload

In particular it looks like you want to implement this:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/#file_picker_callback